# HTML5 Application Cache - Javascript not working

Tags: jquery, html

I'm writing a web app to be used offline on iOS. 
http://www.addictedtocolors.com/pba/pba_eng.html

It's caching everything (html, images, css, js) but it's not executing jquery.

I can't undertand what's wrong and I can't figure out a solution.

**Here's the html**

```
<!doctype html>
<html manifest="offline.appcache">

<head>

<meta charset="utf-8" />
<title>pba</title>
<link type="image/x-icon" rel="shortcut icon" href="img/favicon.ico" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />    
<meta content="yes" name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" />

<!-- iPad (Retina) ICON-->
<link rel="apple-touch-icon-precomposed" sizes="144x144"
href="icon/pba-icon-144x144.png" />
<!-- iPhone (Retina) ICON-->
<link rel="apple-touch-icon-precomposed" sizes="114x114"
href="icon/pba-icon-114x114.png" />
<!-- iPad ICON-->
<link rel="apple-touch-icon-precomposed" sizes="72x72"
href="icon/pba-icon-72x72.png" />
<!-- iPhone ICON -->
<link rel="apple-touch-icon-precomposed"
href="icon/pba-icon-57x57.png" />

<!-- iPhone SPLASHSCREEN-->
<link href="icon/pba-startup-320x460.png" media="(device-width:
320px)" rel="apple-touch-startup-image">
<!-- iPhone (Retina) SPLASHSCREEN-->
<link href="icon/pba-startup-640x920.png" media="(device-width:
320px) and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 2)" rel="apple-touch-startup-image">
<!-- iPad (portrait) SPLASHSCREEN-->
<link href="icon/pba-startup-768x1004.png"
media="(device-width: 768px) and (orientation: portrait)"
rel="apple-touch-startup-image">
<!-- iPad (landscape) SPLASHSCREEN-->
<link href="icon/pba-startup-1024x748.png"
media="(device-width: 768px) and (orientation: landscape)"
rel="apple-touch-startup-image">
<!-- iPad (Retina, portrait) SPLASHSCREEN-->
<link href="icon/pba-startup-1536x2008.png"
media="(device-width: 1536px) and (orientation: portrait) and
(-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 2)" rel="apple-touch-startup-image">
<!-- iPad (Retina, landscape) SPLASHSCREEN-->
<link href="icon/pba-startup-2048x1496.png"
media="(device-width: 1536px) and (orientation: landscape) and
(-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 2)" rel="apple-touch-startup-image">

<!--[if lt IE 9]><script src="js/html5shiv.js"></script><![endif]-->
<!--[if lte IE 9]><link rel="stylesheet" href="css/ie.css" type="text/css" media="screen" /><![endif]-->

<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/1140.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />

<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />  

</head>


<body>

<div class="container">
<div class="row">
    <div class="twelvecol">
        <ul class="rslides">
            <li>
                <a href="img/pagina2/pag_2_1.jpg" class="fancy zoom" id="zoom_2_1">zoom 1</a>
                <a href="img/pagina2/pag_2_2.jpg" class="fancy zoom small" id="zoom_2_2">zoom 2</a>
                <a href="img/pagina2/pag_2_3.jpg" class="fancy zoom small" id="zoom_2_3">zoom 3</a>
                <a href="img/pagina2/pag_2_4.jpg" class="fancy zoom" id="zoom_2_4">zoom 4</a>
                <a href="img/pagina2/pag_2_5.jpg" class="fancy zoom small" id="zoom_2_5">zoom 5</a>
                <a href="img/pagina2/pag_2_6.jpg" class="fancy zoom small" id="zoom_2_6">zoom 6</a>
                <a href="img/pagina2/pag_2_7.jpg" class="fancy zoom" id="zoom_2_7">zoom 7</a>
                <a href="img/pagina2/pag_2_8.jpg" class="fancy zoom small" id="zoom_2_8">zoom 8</a>
                <a href="img/pagina2/pag_2_9.jpg" class="fancy zoom small" id="zoom_2_9">zoom 9</a>
                <img src="img/pba_eng_2.jpg" alt="" />
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="img/pagina3/pag_3_1.jpg" class="fancy zoom" id="zoom_3_1">zoom 1</a>
                <a href="img/pagina3/pag_3_2.jpg" class="fancy zoom" id="zoom_3_2">zoom 2</a>
                <a href="img/pagina3/pag_3_3.jpg" class="fancy zoom" id="zoom_3_3">zoom 3</a>
                <a href="img/pagina3/pag_3_4.jpg" class="fancy zoom" id="zoom_3_4">zoom 4</a>
                <a href="img/pagina3/pag_3_5.jpg" class="fancy zoom" id="zoom_3_5">zoom 5</a>
                <a href="img/pagina3/pag_3_6.jpg" class="fancy zoom" id="zoom_3_6">zoom 6</a>
                <img src="img/pba_eng_3.jpg" alt="" />
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="img/pagina4/pag_4_1.jpg" class="fancy zoom" id="zoom_4_1">zoom 1</a>
                <a href="img/pagina4/pag_4_2.jpg" class="fancy zoom small" id="zoom_4_2">zoom 2</a>
                <a href="img/pagina4/pag_4_3.jpg" class="fancy zoom small" id="zoom_4_3">zoom 3</a>
                <a href="img/pagina4/pag_4_4.jpg" class="fancy zoom small" id="zoom_4_4">zoom 4</a>
                <a href="img/pagina4/pag_4_5.jpg" class="fancy zoom small" id="zoom_4_5">zoom 5</a>
                <a href="img/pagina4/pag_4_6.jpg" class="fancy zoom" id="zoom_4_6">zoom 6</a>                   
                <a href="img/pagina4/pag_4_7.jpg" class="fancy zoom small" id="zoom_4_7">zoom 7</a>
                <a href="img/pagina4/pag_4_8.jpg" class="fancy zoom small" id="zoom_4_8">zoom 8</a>
                <a href="img/pagina4/pag_4_9.jpg" class="fancy zoom small" id="zoom_4_9">zoom 9</a>
                <a href="img/pagina4/pag_4_10.jpg" class="fancy zoom small" id="zoom_4_10">zoom 10</a>
                <a href="img/pagina4/pag_4_11.jpg" class="fancy zoom" id="zoom_4_11">zoom 11</a>
                <a href="img/pagina4/pag_4_12.jpg" class="fancy zoom small" id="zoom_4_12">zoom 12</a>
                <a href="img/pagina4/pag_4_13.jpg" class="fancy zoom small" id="zoom_4_13">zoom 13</a>
                <a href="img/pagina4/pag_4_14.jpg" class="fancy zoom small" id="zoom_4_14">zoom 14</a>
                <a href="img/pagina4/pag_4_15.jpg" class="fancy zoom small" id="zoom_4_15">zoom 15</a>  
                <img src="img/pba_eng_4.jpg" alt="" />
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="img/pagina7/pag_7_1-2-3.jpg" class="fancy zoom" id="zoom_7_1">zoom 1</a>
                <a href="img/pagina7/pag_7_1-2-3.jpg" class="fancy zoom" id="zoom_7_2">zoom 2</a>
                <a href="img/pagina7/pag_7_1-2-3.jpg" class="fancy zoom" id="zoom_7_3">zoom 3</a>
                <a href="img/pagina7/pag_7_4.jpg" class="fancy zoom" id="zoom_7_4">zoom 4</a>
                <a href="img/pagina7/pag_7_5.jpg" class="fancy zoom" id="zoom_7_5">zoom 5</a>
                <a href="img/pagina7/pag_7_6-7.jpg" class="fancy zoom" id="zoom_7_6">zoom 6</a>             
                <a href="img/pagina7/pag_7_6-7.jpg" class="fancy zoom" id="zoom_7_7">zoom 7</a>
                <a href="img/pagina7/pag_7_8.jpg" class="fancy zoom" id="zoom_7_8">zoom 8</a>
                <a href="img/pagina7/pag_7_9.jpg" class="fancy zoom" id="zoom_7_9">zoom 9</a>
                <a href="img/pagina7/pag_7_10.jpg" class="fancy zoom" id="zoom_7_10">zoom 10</a>
                <a href="img/pagina7/pag_7_11.jpg" class="fancy zoom" id="zoom_7_11">zoom 11</a>
                <a href="img/pagina7/pag_7_12.jpg" class="fancy zoom" id="zoom_7_12">zoom 12</a>
                <img src="img/pba_eng_7.jpg" alt="" />
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="img/pagina6/pag_6_1.jpg" class="fancy zoom small" id="zoom_6_1">zoom 1</a>
                <a href="img/pagina6/pag_6_2.jpg" class="fancy zoom small" id="zoom_6_2">zoom 2</a>
                <a href="img/pagina6/pag_6_3.jpg" class="fancy zoom small" id="zoom_6_3">zoom 3</a>
                <a href="img/pagina6/pag_6_4.jpg" class="fancy zoom small" id="zoom_6_4">zoom 4</a>
                <a href="img/pagina6/pag_6_5.jpg" class="fancy zoom small" id="zoom_6_5">zoom 5</a>
                <a href="img/pagina6/pag_6_6.jpg" class="fancy zoom small" id="zoom_6_6">zoom 6</a>             
                <a href="img/pagina6/pag_6_7.jpg" class="fancy zoom small" id="zoom_6_7">zoom 7</a>
                <a href="img/pagina6/pag_6_8.jpg" class="fancy zoom small" id="zoom_6_8">zoom 8</a>
                <a href="img/pagina6/pag_6_9.jpg" class="fancy zoom small" id="zoom_6_9">zoom 9</a>
                <a href="img/pagina6/pag_6_10.jpg" class="fancy zoom small" id="zoom_6_10">zoom 10</a>
                <a href="img/pagina6/pag_6_11.jpg" class="fancy zoom small" id="zoom_6_11">zoom 11</a>
                <a href="img/pagina6/pag_6_12.jpg" class="fancy zoom small" id="zoom_6_12">zoom 12</a>
                <a href="img/pagina6/pag_6_13.jpg" class="fancy zoom small" id="zoom_6_13">zoom 13</a>
                <a href="img/pagina6/pag_6_14.jpg" class="fancy zoom small" id="zoom_6_14">zoom 14</a>
                <a href="img/pagina6/pag_6_15.jpg" class="fancy zoom small" id="zoom_6_15">zoom 15</a>
                <a href="img/pagina6/pag_6_16.jpg" class="fancy zoom small" id="zoom_6_16">zoom 16</a>          
                <a href="img/pagina6/pag_6_17.jpg" class="fancy zoom small" id="zoom_6_17">zoom 17</a>
                <a href="img/pagina6/pag_6_18.jpg" class="fancy zoom small" id="zoom_6_18">zoom 18</a>
                <a href="img/pagina6/pag_6_19.jpg" class="fancy zoom small" id="zoom_6_19">zoom 19</a>
                <a href="img/pagina6/pag_6_20.jpg" class="fancy zoom small" id="zoom_6_20">zoom 20</a>
                <a href="img/pagina6/pag_6_21.jpg" class="fancy zoom small" id="zoom_6_21">zoom 21</a>
                <a href="img/pagina6/pag_6_22.jpg" class="fancy zoom small" id="zoom_6_22">zoom 22</a>
                <a href="img/pagina6/pag_6_23.jpg" class="fancy zoom small" id="zoom_6_23">zoom 23</a>
                <a href="img/pagina6/pag_6_24.jpg" class="fancy zoom small" id="zoom_6_24">zoom 24</a>
                <img src="img/pba_eng_6.jpg" alt="" />
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="img/pagina5/pag_5_1.jpg" class="fancy zoom big" id="zoom_5_1">zoom 1</a>
                <a href="img/pagina5/pag_5_2.jpg" class="fancy zoom big" id="zoom_5_2">zoom 2</a>
                <a href="img/pagina5/pag_5_3.jpg" class="fancy zoom big" id="zoom_5_3">zoom 3</a>
                <a href="img/pagina5/pag_5_4.jpg" class="fancy zoom big" id="zoom_5_4">zoom 4</a>
                <img src="img/pba_eng_5.jpg" alt="" />
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="img/pagina8/pag_8_1.jpg" class="fancy zoom" id="zoom_8_1">zoom 1</a>
                <img src="img/pba_eng_8.jpg" alt="" />
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="img/pagina9/pag_9_1.jpg" class="fancy zoom" id="zoom_9_1">zoom 1</a>
                <img src="img/pba_eng_9.jpg" alt="" />
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="pba_ita.html" class="ita">ITALIANO</a>
                <a href="pba_eng.html" class="eng">ENGLISH</a>
                <img src="img/pba_cover.jpg" alt="" />
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
<script src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/responsiveslides.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.fancybox.pack.js"></script>
<script src="js/debug.js"></script>
<script>
$(window).load(function(){
  setTimeout(function(){
    window.scrollTo(0, 1);
  }, 0);
});
$(function () {
$(".rslides").responsiveSlides({
    auto: false,
    pager: false,
    nav: true,
    speed: 500
});
});
$(document).ready(function() {
$(".fancy").fancybox({
    padding: 0, 
    openEffect : 'fade',
    openSpeed  : 250,   
    closeEffect : 'fade',
    closeSpeed  : 250,  
    closeClick : true
});
});
</script>
```

**And the offline.appcache**

```
CACHE MANIFEST
#Vers. 1.0

CACHE:
index.html
pba_eng.html
pba_ita.html
css/1140.css
css/styles.css
js/jquery.fancybox.pack.js
js/jquery.min.js
js/responsiveslides.min.js
js/debug.js
icon/pba-icon-57x57.png
icon/pba-icon-72x72.png
icon/pba-icon-114x114.png
icon/pba-icon-144x144.png
icon/pba-startup-320x460.png
icon/pba-startup-640x920.png
icon/pba-startup-768x1004.png
icon/pba-startup-1024x748.png
icon/pba-startup-1536x2008.png
icon/pba-startup-2048x1496.png
img/blank.gif
img/fancybox_loading.gif
img/shim.gif
img/themes.gif
img/fancybox_sprite.png
img/favicon.ico
img/pba_cover.jpg
img/pba_eng_2.jpg
img/pba_eng_3.jpg
img/pba_eng_4.jpg
img/pba_eng_5.jpg
img/pba_eng_6.jpg
img/pba_eng_7.jpg
img/pba_eng_8.jpg
img/pba_eng_9.jpg
img/pba_ita_2.jpg
img/pba_ita_3.jpg
img/pba_ita_4.jpg
img/pba_ita_5.jpg
img/pba_ita_6.jpg
img/pba_ita_7.jpg
img/pba_ita_8.jpg
img/pba_ita_9.jpg
img/pagina2/pag_2_1.jpg
img/pagina2/pag_2_2.jpg
img/pagina2/pag_2_3.jpg
img/pagina2/pag_2_4.jpg
img/pagina2/pag_2_5.jpg
img/pagina2/pag_2_6.jpg
img/pagina2/pag_2_7.jpg
img/pagina2/pag_2_8.jpg
img/pagina2/pag_2_9.jpg
img/pagina3/pag_3_1.jpg
img/pagina3/pag_3_2.jpg
img/pagina3/pag_3_3.jpg
img/pagina3/pag_3_4.jpg
img/pagina3/pag_3_5.jpg
img/pagina3/pag_3_6.jpg
img/pagina4/pag_4_1.jpg
img/pagina4/pag_4_2.jpg
img/pagina4/pag_4_3.jpg
img/pagina4/pag_4_4.jpg
img/pagina4/pag_4_5.jpg
img/pagina4/pag_4_6.jpg
img/pagina4/pag_4_7.jpg
img/pagina4/pag_4_8.jpg
img/pagina4/pag_4_9.jpg
img/pagina4/pag_4_10.jpg
img/pagina4/pag_4_11.jpg
img/pagina4/pag_4_12.jpg
img/pagina4/pag_4_13.jpg
img/pagina4/pag_4_14.jpg
img/pagina4/pag_4_15.jpg
img/pagina5/pag_5_1.jpg
img/pagina5/pag_5_2.jpg
img/pagina5/pag_5_3.jpg
img/pagina5/pag_5_4.jpg
img/pagina6/pag_6_1.jpg
img/pagina6/pag_6_2.jpg
img/pagina6/pag_6_3.jpg
img/pagina6/pag_6_4.jpg
img/pagina6/pag_6_5.jpg
img/pagina6/pag_6_6.jpg
img/pagina6/pag_6_7.jpg
img/pagina6/pag_6_8.jpg
img/pagina6/pag_6_9.jpg
img/pagina6/pag_6_10.jpg
img/pagina6/pag_6_11.jpg
img/pagina6/pag_6_12.jpg
img/pagina6/pag_6_13.jpg
img/pagina6/pag_6_14.jpg
img/pagina6/pag_6_15.jpg
img/pagina6/pag_6_16.jpg
img/pagina6/pag_6_17.jpg
img/pagina6/pag_6_18.jpg
img/pagina6/pag_6_19.jpg
img/pagina6/pag_6_20.jpg
img/pagina6/pag_6_21.jpg
img/pagina6/pag_6_22.jpg
img/pagina6/pag_6_23.jpg
img/pagina6/pag_6_24.jpg
img/pagina7/pag_7_1-2-3.jpg
img/pagina7/pag_7_4.jpg
img/pagina7/pag_7_5.jpg
img/pagina7/pag_7_6-7.jpg
img/pagina7/pag_7_8.jpg
img/pagina7/pag_7_9.jpg
img/pagina7/pag_7_10.jpg
img/pagina7/pag_7_11.jpg
img/pagina7/pag_7_12.jpg
img/pagina8/pag_8_1.jpg
img/pagina9/pag_9_1.jpg
```

Any advice is welcome. Thanks

Comment: try adding type="text/javascript" attr to your script

Comment: nope, nothing change :(

Answer (score 0):

Doesn't jQuery's load function execute a ajax-call ? http://api.jquery.com/load/

When entering your homepage

```
$(window).load(function(){
  setTimeout(function(){
    window.scrollTo(0, 1);
  }, 0);
});
```

Does nothing in the console. But it's responding, so jQuery is there.

Maybe try clear your cache (chrome://appcache-internals/).